# A function that returns true when the Author is a certain role is_author(admin)?

Tags: php

I need a function that returns true when the author is an admin or an editor or of a certain role.

I can't use is_single because I have set up a forum and there are a million singles out there and I need a different layout for THE posts (the ones written in the blog by admins and editors) than from the forum entries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`author_can()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/author_can) seems to fit.

Example:

```
if( author_can( get_the_ID(), 'administrator' ) )
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to use it? Thanks

Comment: Added example. I think docs cover function quite well, anything in particular you have trouble with?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it worked. I have just one question, how do I add a second role so that it triggers then too? like for example editor.

Comment: Make two checks and join them with PHP _or_ operator - `||`. This is more of PHP basics than WP.